# CSS HTML Icon Issue

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Building out a site for my company and while I'm 90% there, the social icons that link to our social media accounts will not populate with icons.

Tried playing around with the CSS but believe the error is in the `<body>`. Also tried `><i` between the class but then it errors with a "Refused to Connect".

```css
div.centered {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.centered a {
  padding: 10px 12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div.centered a:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.fb {
  background: #1877f2;
}

.insta {
  background: #fb3958;
}

.twitter {
  background: #00acee;
}

.linkedin {
  background: #0e76a8;
}

.youtube {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="centered">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/gemvisioncorp" class="fb" class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank"></i>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gemvisioncorp/" class="insta" class="fa fa-instagram" target="_blank"></i>
  </a>

  <a href="https://twitter.com/gemvisioncorp" class="twitter" class="fa fa-twitter" target="_blank"></i>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/gemvision" class="linkedin" class="fa fa-linkedin" target="_blank"></i>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/gemvisioncorp" class="youtube" class="fa fa-youtube" target="_blank"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you have just `</i>` inside your anchor? Did you read the fontawesome documentation for how to insert their icons? You also can't put `class` twice on the same element. Try something like `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/gemvisioncorp" class="fb" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>`

Comment: Wow. That did it. I was putting it between the class and it was erroring. I'm using a website builder Im new to, and this helped SO MUCH. TY!

Answer (score 0):

You have two `class=` assignments in one html tag. Only the first one will be evaluated.

Join them to one `class` assignment:

```css
div.centered {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.centered a {
  padding: 10px 12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div.centered a:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.fb {
  background: #1877f2;
}

.insta {
  background: #fb3958;
}

.twitter {
  background: #00acee;
}

.linkedin {
  background: #0e76a8;
}

.youtube {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="centered">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/gemvisioncorp" class="fb fa fa-facebook" target="_blank"></i>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gemvisioncorp/" class="insta fa fa-instagram" target="_blank"></i>
  </a>

  <a href="https://twitter.com/gemvisioncorp" class="twitter fa fa-twitter" target="_blank"></i>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/gemvision" class="linkedin fa fa-linkedin" target="_blank"></i>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/gemvisioncorp" class="youtube fa fa-youtube" target="_blank"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```